# wp-admin redirects to 404

Tags: wp-admin, 404-error

Yesterday I logged onto my site and found that when I log in as an admin I get a 404 error as seen below:

[image: 404 Error]

I have done a bit of research and uploaded a backup, modified my `.htaccess` file to below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but to no avail.

Trying to access anything that is `/wp-admin/` results in a 404 inclusive of the `wp-stats` image as seen in the picture.

I have downloaded a new version of Wordpress and uploaded it's `wp-admin` folder.

Aside from the above error, the site works fine.

**EDIT**

SHH Error log:

```
[Fri Apr 13 10:21:47 2012] [error] [client {redacted}] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://dailywealthreport.com.au/wp-login.php
[Fri Apr 13 10:21:50 2012] [error] [client {redacted}] Premature end of script headers: admin.php, referer: http://dailywealthreport.com.au/wp-admin/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One *possible* reason is that the /wp-admin has been reset to something else, for security reasons. The [WP Better Security](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wp-security/) plugin can do this. I know, because I have in the past turned on a bunch of this plugin's options, without thinking too much about it, including the one that re-writes the /wp-admin URL so you need to go to /admin. -- And then *I* forgot about it too, which was frustrating!

Try moving all the plugins out of wp-content/plugins (to turn them off temporarily), then see if it works normally. Then, you can selectively re-turn-on the plugins and see what's going on.

Comment: That does work, but the plugin that sorts out my logging in has horrendous support for the price I am paying for it, and on top of that the code is hashed, so I can't trying and find out the problem there. Do you know of a ways to try and sort it out via WP?

Comment: "To try and sort it out via WP?" -- Can you clarify what you're wanting?

Comment: added some more info as to the error that is actually coming up according to the log. I am looking for a way to sort out what is going on independent of the plugin.

Comment: As listed in the OP, I have been googling the answer hence my posting up here for more solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Finding The Cause Of The WP-admin Redirection & Refresh Error

1. List item
2. Plugin Conflict
3. Theme Conflict
4. Reach Out To Your Web Hosting Support
5. .htaccess File Corruption
6. Site URL Error
7. Cookies And Cache

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same thing, tried everything from reinstalling WP, resetting my .htaccess and doing things that only made things worse. Turns out it I should have done was clear out my own Cookies And Cache. Problem fixed.